# calculation of combinations of 2 patially overlapping group.

Tags: probability, combinations, card-games

I am having trouble calculating the following question: There are 42 people in different groups. Group A have 16 people. Group B have 11 people. Group C have 21 people. There are 6 people that are both in Group A and Group B. Suppose 5 people are randomly selected from 3 groups. calculate the probability that at least 1 people is from group A and at least one from B.

I am having trouble deal with the overlapping elements while calculating the combinations.

S = 42, A = 16, B = 11, A∩B = 6, C = 21

My first attempt was this: (16C1 x 11C1 x 15C3)/42C5
Then I realize that the overlapping elements could be an issue. I tried to separate it into three parts. That is, calculate the combinations without dealing with the overlapping elements.
That is: ((16C1 x 5C1 x 21C3)+(10C1 x 11C1 x 21C3)+(10C0 x 5C0 x 6C2 x 21C3))/42C5 = 0.32

Then I realized that I forgot the "at least" condition
So I tried this:

let A = 10, B = 5, C = 6, and D = 21

the probability of at least 1A1B, 1A1C, 1B1C, 2C

Pr = 1 - P[0A0B0C5D] - P[1A0B0C4D] - P[2A0B0C3D] - P[3A0B0C2D] - P[4A0B0C1D] - P[5A0B0C0D] - P[0A1B0C4D] - P[0A2B0C3D]- P[0A3B0C2D] - P[0A4B0C1D] - P[0A5B0C0D] - P[0A0B1C4D] = 70.465

not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You need to first show what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck.

Comment: I have added my work so far to the question.

Comment: Do the rest of the 42-11-16 =15 cards have any identical cards in them?

Comment: By five "hands", I take it that a total of $5$ **cards** are drawn ?

Comment: The rest of cards should be 21 since there are 6 identical cards. And they don’t have identical cards

Comment: Yes, 5 cards are drawn from 42 cards.

Comment: It is not adding up to $42$ , only $39$ $6+6+16+11$

Comment: It is 16 +11 + 21 - 6.

Comment: Pl post **exact** question. You are creating confusion.

Comment: it is not a question from textbook or test. I am sorry for confusion I made. I will try to restate my question.

Comment: Maybe it is better to think them as people. Group A have 16 people, group B have 11 people, 8 people are both in group A and B. That is S = 42, A = 16, B = 11, A∩B = 6, ¬A∪B = 21.

Comment: You mean $6$ people are common to A and B.

Comment: yes 6 people are common to A and B

Answer (score 1):

Taking that one with label A and one with label B, which may be a single card labelled both A and B is mandatory,

groups that aren't "good" are those drawn from $16 A's$ and irrelevant $15$  + those drawn from $11 B's$ and irrelevant $15$

Thus $Pr = 1 - \dfrac{\binom{31}5 +\binom{26}5}{\binom{42}5}$

---

*ADDED*

Re your further comments, "bad" combos will be

$A\; B\; AB\; C$
$0\;\; 0\;\;\; 0\;\;\; 5$
$0\;\; 0\;\;\; 1\;\;\; 4$
$0\;\; 1\;\;\; 0\;\;\; 4$
$1\;\; 0\;\;\; 0\;\;\; 4$

Comment: I think I made another confusion again. When I say I need 1 card for A and B, I mean that I need two cards which one is from A and one is from B, or 2 of them are from A∩B. I am so sorry.

Comment: also with the "at least" condition

Comment: I have noted the "bad combos" to be subtracted. $AB$ is the common group with $6$ and $C$ is the irrelevant $21$.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Good night from here ! $\;\;$ :)